# The merchant does not accept payments of this type

Tags: ios, paypal

I am getting this error while payment: `the merchant does not accept payments of this type`.

The error occurs in `ios` (`Android` is working with the same id).

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You might probably use Direct Payment API but your PayPal account does not support it. In iOS, did you set your payment method = Credit card? If yes, this is the reason why you are getting the error. Try changing to payment method = paypal and run it once again.